# Swift: Refresh Tab Bar Background Colour Dynamically

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I've created a config manager to update UI settings without restarting. Most settings you can just force a redraw however it appears to be more limited with the tab bar.

I update the tab bar within my `UITabBarController` with the following when I receive a config change notification (note: this could be anytime after `viewDidLoad`):

```
self.tabBar.backgroundColor = tabBarBackgroundColour
```

This does update the colour but only after about 5-10 seconds.

I've tried various ways to force an update using `setNeedsLayout` and `setNeedsDisplay` on both the tab bar and the view but none of them work.

```
self.tabBar.setNeedsLayout()
self.tabBar.setNeedsDisplay()
```

**or**

```
self.view.setNeedsLayout()
self.view.setNeedsDisplay()
```

I've also tried updating the individual tab bar items as I see other people have had similar issues when updating images but to no avail.

Comment: are you sure you are updating the color from the main thread? I recall that if you update UI from background Thread it delay the draw sometimes...

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are updating the background color on the main thread.

```
   DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
     self?.tabBar.backgroundColor = tabBarBackgroundColour
   }
```

Comment: Why do you need [weak self] in? why you don't use [unowned self] in? or better why not only DispatchQueue.main.async { 
     self?.tabBar.backgroundColor = tabBarBackgroundColour
   }